# Command not found ping (M1 mac)

Tags: zsh

I'm running into a strange problem where if I run `ping` in my `zsh`, I get:

```
zsh: command not found: ping
```

My `echo $PATH` is:

```
/Users/jlangr/opt/anaconda3/envs/b39/bin:/usr/local/include:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/jlangr/.local/bin:/Users/jlangr/miniconda3/bin:/miniconda3/bin:/Users/jlangr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jlangr/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/jlangr/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbineval
```

I don't think I've missed anything up.

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: `bash -c 'find / -name ping 2> /dev/null'` - and wait ... if it's not found you'll probably have to install a package of some sort where it's included.

Comment: It should be probably `/sbin/ping` add `/sbin` do your path if it's there.

Comment: @Rob It was also tagged [tag:bash] when I wrote my previous comment and I made it `bash -c ...` since I have no clue how [tag:zsh] interprets `2> /dev/null`. If he in fact has [tag:bash] installed, my command should find `ping`. It found 6 `ping`s on my machine. One softlinked from `/usr/sbin/ping -> /usr/bin/ping` (but I don't have a Mac so his paths will probably be different).

Comment: Where actually is `ping` located on your platform?

Comment: It is located on `/sbin/ping` It works from there. But I wonder why I can't detect it normally. I also have issues with other commands.

Comment: The last entry in your `PATH` is `/sbineval`. It looks like you appended something to your path that you didn't intend to in one configuration file or another, and so `/sbin` is no longer on your path.

Comment: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/sbin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`  -- worked for me on M1 mac

Answer (score 2):

On **zsh**, you can append the path to your .zshrc file:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/sbin"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Remember to open a new instance for the command to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit likely was the `sbin` not being appended correctly to path. The solution was to make sure that `sbin` was included:

```
PATH=/opt/local/sbin:"${PATH}"
```